# DLC has odd unit button effects, may prevent founding a religion

Tags: civilization-5

I've played Civ 5, with and without DLCs for over 15,000 hours, and have never had a problem founding a religion.  Am trying three DLC options, for the first time:
Zootopia civilization (my civ);
Dalek civilization (computer);
Cybermen civilization (computer).

On turn 20, found enough faith in a ruin to get a pantheon.  I also built Stonehenge.  So I know the computer sides haven't founded all the available religions.

I just got a great prophet, and the DLC has the same odd quirk for all units, saying it's earned a promotion.  No button available for using the prophet to found a religion.

I'm hoping someone has found a hotkey or keyboard combo that commits the prophet to founding a religion.

Oh, and yes, the prophet is in my one city.

Comment: There is no "Zootopia", "Dalek", or "Cybermen" DLC for Civ 5. Are you sure you're not talking about mods instead?

Comment: Found a work-around.  Saved, exited to main menu, reloaded saved game, and the "Found Religion" button was there, for the great prophet.  And yes, they're mods.  I thought of them as also DLC, because they are downloadable content (only from the community).